# What's the best way to create HTML Live Tiles?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I would like to create live tiles like windows, which can show things like notifications, time, etc., but I would like to create them in html and javascript. I have all the javascript pieces ready but I wanted to know if it would be wise to use an iframe for every tile because the tiles can be created dynamically and all have their own code. Here I ask myself whether IFrames represent a performance problem or whether I can use them with a clear conscience

Comment: IMAO it´s weird for someone who will eventually have to read your code. What about using PHP include()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is designed to embed an other HTML document.

I don't see any performance problem.

Here is a nice doc at MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

If it is your purpose, why not use them, but maybe are you looking for another approach like web components...?

Hope this helps.